# How to login to Oracle12c using sqldeveloper when I only know credentials that work with sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, sqlplus

So I have this old Oracle database that I want to some migrate to some other db system.
You'd think that username and password is straight forward, but not when using something by Oracle.

So for sqlplus I just run the command `sqlplus` and it asks for username and password.
As the user I type in "orcl as sysdba" and then I type in the password. This works.
But SQL Developer doesn't accept that. It has a input field for username. And a select box with options like "standard", "SYSDBA" etc. No matter what I type in it always rejects the credentials.

It also asks for a SID, for which I just use ORCL, because it's the only thing I found where it doesn't complain about that.

I know that "orcl as sysdba" is the correct username for sqlplus. So what is the username for SQL Developer? Why is it not the same? Why does sqlplus not ask for the SID?

[image: Screenshot of how credentials are declined]

It's Oracle 12c from an old project. There is supposed to be a Flash tool at https://localhost:5500/em but the login also doesn't work there.

I have imported a table space from a dump that was made on the production server. I used Oracle 12c because the dump file indicated that this was the version used to dump the data.

Comment: You should remove the last 2 paragraphs and ask them each as new questions as they are irrelevant to your main question.

Comment: `ORA-01017` means the username and password combination is incorrect. Check that the user you are trying to connect to exists and that the password is correct for that user.

Answer (score 1):

Log into Oracle using SQL/Plus as `SYSDBA` and reset the password for a user account and then log into that account on SQL Developer using the newly reset password.

In SQL/Plus, from the account with the `SYSDBA` privileges, if you want to change the password off the `my_user` user then:

```sql
ALTER USER my_user IDENTIFIED BY MyNewPassword123;
```

> I know that `"orcl as sysdba"` is the correct username for sqlplus. So what is the username for SQL Developer? Why is it not the same? Why does sqlplus not ask for the SID?

It is not a correct username. `orcl` is the username (or maybe the SID) and `SYSDBA` is the elevated level of privileges you wish to use once connected. You do not need to specify a username if you are connecting via SQL/Plus from the file system local to the database with `SYSDBA` privileges and can just use:

```
sqlplus / AS SYSDBA
```

and [your access is authenticated using operating system authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DE8A79BD-FAE4-4364-98FF-D2BD992A06E7.htm#ADMQS0361).

If you want to connect to a user with `SYSDBA` privileges then you probably want the default `sys` or `system` users (and to be careful what you do when connected as those users as you will have full control of the database and can do anything, including changing settings so you break the database).

Something like this:

[image]

---

If you want to find out what user you are connected as (in SQL/Plus) then:

```sql
SELECT USER FROM DUAL;
```

You can then use the same username that that outputs (and the appropriate password, which you can reset using the commands above if required) in SQL Developer.

Comment: So "orcl" is the username and "sysdba" is the role. This works using sqlplus (using `orcl as sysdba`) but not in sqldev. I know the password is correct as it works using sqlplus. What would be the point of resetting the password?

Comment: @ClaudeMartin If you use `sqlplus / as sysdba` then you will not be asked a password and Oracle will use operating system authentication; if you then connect to the same user in SQL Developer you would need to supply a password and, if you don't know the password from never needing it in sqlplus then it may need resetting. If you are using a password in `sqlplus` then it doesn't need resetting.